# What is the probability that $\gcd(a,b)$ is prime or twice a prime?

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$. Denote the set of prime numbers by $P$.
[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97041/what-is-the-probability-that-two-numbers-are-relatively-prime) it is mentioned that the probability that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ tends to $\frac{6}{\pi^2}=0.60792 \ldots$

> What is the probability that $\gcd(a,b) \in P$ or $\gcd(a,b) \in 2P$?

Thank you very much!

**Edit:** It was mentioned in the comments that my question before editing (= probability of $\gcd(a,b) \in P$) has already been asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860366/probability-that-two-random-integers-have-only-one-prime-factor-in-common), and the answer is $0.274933 \ldots$.

I still have several (probably trivial) questions concerning the above probabilities:

**(1)** Are the above calculations for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$? What happens for $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$?
(If, for example, $a=0$, then $\gcd(a,b)=b$).

**(2)** If the above calculations are for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, is it true then that the probability that $\gcd(a,b) \in \{1\} \cup P$ is 
$0.60792 \ldots + 0.274933 \ldots= 0.881 \ldots$? (I think yes).

**(3)** I have now added to my question "or twice a prime", namely, $\gcd(a,b) \in 2P$. **Edit 2:** I now see that this was also answered in the above mentioned [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860366/probability-that-two-random-integers-have-only-one-prime-factor-in-common) (please notice the last two comments there).

Comment: This has been answered already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860366/probability-that-two-random-integers-have-only-one-prime-factor-in-common).

Comment: @DietrichBurde But having a prime factor in common isn't the same as having a gcd of 1.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thank you very much! Indeed, it is proved there that the probability that $\gcd(a,b) \in P$ is 0.274933...

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ vs $\mathbb N$ doesn't matter, as $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(|a|,|b|)$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, thank you! What about $\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$? Are the two probabilities (for $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and for $\gcd(a,b) \in P$)  the same as for $\mathbb{N}$? The first probability seems to me the same, since we only exclude $(a,b) \in \{(0,1),(1,0), (0,0) \}$. I am not sure about the second probability (we exclude $(a,b) \in (0,P) \cup (P,0)$).

Comment: @user237522 Including 0 makes no difference in the probabilities; the two boundary lines make up avanishingly small percentage of the plane. (More formally, the probability is generally defined as the limit for $N\to\infty$ of the probability for $a,b\leq N$, and the portion of that set with either $a$ or $b$ equal to $0$ is proportional to $1/N$.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, thank you for your explanation (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37520/on-the-probability-that-two-positive-integers-are-relatively-prime?rq=1 is somewhat relevant).