# What is the probability that $\gcd(a,b)$ is twice a prime?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. Denote the set of prime numbers by $P$.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860366/probability-that-two-random-integers-have-only-one-prime-factor-in-common) it was shown that the probability that $\gcd(a,b) \in P$ is $0.2749 \ldots$.

> What is the probability that $\gcd(a,b) \in 2P$?

Any hints and comments are welcome!

**Edit:** 
In the [above link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860366/probability-that-two-random-integers-have-only-one-prime-factor-in-common) it is also mentioned that the probability that 
$\gcd(a,b)=1$ is $0.6079\ldots$.
Then the probability that $\gcd(a,b) \in \{1\} \cup P$ is
$0.6079\ldots + 0.2749 \ldots = 0.8822 \ldots$.
Thereore, the probability that $\gcd(a,b) \in 2P$ should be strictly less than $0.1178 \ldots$.

(Also notice that the probability that $\gcd(a,b) \in \{1\} \cup P \cup P^2 \cup P^3 \cup \cdots=\{1\} \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} P^i$ is $1$,
we must have 'very small' probabilities that $\gcd(a,b) \in P^m$, for a fixed $m \geq 2$).

Answer (score 5):

Hint: For this to hold, $a$ and $b$ must both be even, and after dividing both by 2, their gcd must be prime. Can you use that to figure out the answer?

Comment: Thank you for the hints. So the probability is also $0.2749\ldots$? Since we can write $a=2pA$ and $b=2pB$, with $p$ prime and $\gcd(A,B)=1$, and consider $\frac{a}{2}$ and $\frac{b}{2}$ instead? We have, $\gcd(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2})=\gcd(pA,pB)=p$.

Comment: @user237522 Not exactly, as "uniformly chosen" $A$ and $B$ aren't necessarily even...

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut, thanks for the hint. However, I still do not know the answer..

Comment: You should look more carefully at the linked article. The answer there can tell you how (for fixed $p\in P$) the probability of $\gcd(a,b)=p$ relates to the probability of $\gcd(a,b)=2p$.

Comment: @rogerl, thank you. (Could you please elaborate your answer?).